# I replaced pip for python 2 by installing pip3 with easy_install3 pip. How do I get pip to point at python 2's version?

Tags: python, pip

I'm on an Ubuntu 12.04 system and I need to use python3 and pip3.  Turns out I shouldn't have installed pip3 with easy_install3, because `pip` now points to pip3 from `pip -V`.  I have tried reinstalling both python and python-pip, but it hasn't fixed anything.  How can I get the box back to the way it was?  Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config pip`?

Comment: There are no alternatives is what I get.  I then went through all of them, and there is nothing in reference to pip anywhere, at least from options that have more than one alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/pip*` are just python scripts.

1. Copy pip2

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/bin/pip2 /usr/bin/pip
   ```
2. Edit the new `/usr/bin/pip` and change `'pip2'` to `'pip'`:

   `sudo nano /usr/bin/pip`

   This is a copy from Ubuntu 14.04:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/python
   # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.5.4','console_scripts','pip'
   __requires__ = 'pip==1.5.4'
   import sys
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       sys.exit(
           load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
       )
   ```

Well, `/usr/bin/pip2` isn't in place. Purge then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

To check installed files:

```
dpkg -L python-pip
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I don't have a pip2 in /usr/bin, I did try looking for it before.  It's also not in my pip tab complete options.  In those I have pip (which is for python 3.2), pip3, pip3.2, and pip3.4 which I put in there after compiling python 3.4 from source into opt.  I don't even know where to find the original pip to try linking it.

Comment: @jacobcase94, I've updated the answer